# How can I create a registry key on all domain machines with group policy?

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, domain, windows-registry

I have a domain with a controller and joined workstations. I want to create a registry item on all of the connected workstations using a group policy.

I have created a group policy and tried to create a registry key two ways.

1. I tried selecting New > Registry Item, selecting "Create" as the action and then filling it in with the key and value. This creates the registry item on the local machine (my domain controller).
2. I selected New > Registry Wizard, entered the network name of one of the domain workstations, and then was able to browse that workstation's registry, but as far as I can tell I am not able to add a registry item from there.

Is there a way that I can add a registry item to all of the domain-joined workstations at once using group policy?

Comment: 1. sounds like you attached the policy to the wrong OU (DCs instead of workstations)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider it is not attached to an OU, it is just under the domain

Comment: Did you run `gpupdate` on your clients during your tests? Because that method should work.

Comment: Yes and restarted them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.

First, I created a registry item on my domain controller. Then I created a new GPO, new registry wizard, selected the local system and browsed to the registry key I created.

Then I clicked into the registry wizard folders that were created, edited the properties and changed the action from Update to Create.

Ran gpupdate /force and restarted the client workstation, went into regedit and it worked!